# Computing $Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $G=\{A \in GL_n( \mathbb{C}) : a_{ii}=1$ and $a_{ij}=0$ when $i<j\}$. I see that $G$ is a group, a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. My question is, what is $Z(G)$ and how do we compute it?

When $n=2$, I see that $G$ will be abelian so of course we just have $Z(G)=G$.

When $n=3$, however, it is not abelian. We have $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a & b \\ 0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & e & f \\ 0 & 1 & g \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & e & f \\ 0 & 1 & g \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a & b \\ 0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ if and only if $ag=ce$.

So, $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a & b \\ 0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \in Z(G)$ iff the above is true for any choice of $e,g$ (i.e. iff $a=c=0$).

Thus $Z(G)$ is merely the set $\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & b \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} : b \in \mathbb{C} \}$.

But what do we do for $n=4,5,etc.$?

Bonus question: Will our result for $Z(G)$ depend on the fact that we are using the field $F= \mathbb{C}$? My guess is that it will work for any field of $char(F)=0$, but for general fields I have some doubts it will be the same.

Comment: Whoever labelled my question as a duplicate should observe that my $G$ has virtually nothing to do with that other question.

Comment: Isn't it that you have to consider transvections ? Isn't the center the group of diagonal matrices ? Commutativity with all the T_ij will yield M=M^T, thus M is diagonal since it is trigular ? And this should be working on any commutative ring, not just on the field of complex numbers

Comment: @Anthony I am taking the center of $G$, not the center of $GL_n( \mathbb{C})$. (I defined $G$ to be the set of upper triangular matrices having all 1's on the main diagonal). Observe that, when $n=2$, $Z(G)$ contains $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 42 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ which is NOT a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Relevant: [the wiki page on the Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group)

Comment: For $n=3$, your statement amounts to saying that the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&a&b\\&1&c\\&&1}
$$
is in the center if and only if $ag = ce$ for all choices of $e,g$.  This holds if and only if $a = c = 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom +1 So it seems the center is therefore those matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & b \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. But what about for larger $n$? I am intimidated at the thought of repeating this logic on a $1000 \times 1000$ matrix!

Comment: If you look at the subgroup $U$ of $G$ of the elements which have $0$ entries in the rows $2..n$ (except for the diagonal $1$s) isn't this a maximal abelian subgroup? And so contains the centre. Same for $V$ the subgroup with zeros except in last column (except the diag $1$s.) So centre lies in $U\cap V$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician That's a neat argument!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $n \times n$ case, every element of your group can be written in the form
$$
M = I + \sum_{i < j} a_{ij} E_{ij}
$$
where $E_{ij} = e_i e_j^T$ is the matrix with a $1$ in the $(i,j)$ entry.  $e_i$ denotes the $i$th standard basis vector.

First, note that $M$ will be in the center of $G$ if and only if $ME_{ij} = E_{ij}M$ for all $i<j$ (which is true if and only if $M(I + E_{ij}) = (I + E_{ij})M$ for all $i<j$).  We note also that for any $i,j,p,q,$ we have
$$
E_{ij}E_{pq} = e_ie_j^Te_pe_q^T = (e_j^Te_p)e_ie_q^T = 
\begin{cases}
E_{iq} & j=p\\
0 & j\neq p
\end{cases}.
$$

Now, for a fixed $1 \leq p<q\leq n$ and upper-triangular $M$, we compute
$$
E_{pq}M = E_{pq} + \sum_{i < j} m_{ij} E_{pq}E_{ij}
= E_{pq}+ \sum_{q<j}m_{qj} E_{pq}E_{qj}\\
= E_{pq}+ \sum_{j>q}m_{qj} E_{pj}
= e_p(e_q + m_{q,q+1}e_{q+1} + \cdots + m_{q,n}e_n)^T
$$
And similarly, 
$$
ME_{pq} = (m_{1,p}e_1 + \cdots + m_{p-1,p}e_{p-1} + e_p)e_q^T.
$$

Now, what conditions on the entries $m_{ij}$ ensure that $E_{qp}M = ME_{pq}$? Note that these equations place no constraints on the entry $m_{1n}$, and verify that all other entries $m_{ij}$ (for $1\leq i < j \leq n$) appear in the equations above for some choice of $p$ and $q$.

In other words, we should find that $M$ lies in the center of $G$ if and only if all entries above the diagonal are zero, except possibly for $m_{1n}$.  The characteristic of the underlying field is irrelevant since none of these calculations required division.

Comment: There must be an error in my logic somewhere since the results don't agree for $n = 3$. However, I hope this will be useful nevertheless.

Comment: A different perspective on the computation: for a fixed $1 \leq p<q$ and upper-triangular $M$, have
$$
ME_{pq} = (Me_p) e_q^T
$$
which is the $p$th column of $M$ written in the $q$th column of an $n \times n$ matrix. Similarly,
$$
E_{pq}M = e_p (e_q^TM)
$$
which is the $q$th row of $M$ written in the $p$th row.

Comment: I had an error in my $E_{pq}M$ calculation; comment and latest edit is correct

Comment: *NB:* $$E_{ij}E_{pq} = e_ie_j^Te_pe_q^T = (e_j^Te_p)e_iee_q^T = 
\begin{cases}
E_{iq} & j=p\\
0 & j\neq p
\end{cases}$$ can be expressed as $$E_{ij}E_{pq} =\delta_{jp}E_{iq},$$ where $\delta_{jp}$ is the Kronecker delta.